# Delete file from remote server in unix

Tags: unix

I have wrongly uploaded a file in a remote server through ftp connection.
Now when i tried connecting back and deleting the file from this remote server, i am getting this error message
"550  Directory /xhen/Input/aaaaa.txt does not exist.  Directory not deleted."

What should be the right approach to delete file.

Comment: Command i used on remote server to delete file is : rm -f file_name

Answer (score 1):

1. Connect using FTP to the server
2. CD to the correct directory (`cd /xhen/Input/`)
3. `delete aaaaa.txt`

Answer (score 0):

1. ssh username@
2. Enter password of remote
3. rm -f /filepath/file

Comment: How do you know he has `ssh` access?  And uses password authentication?

Comment: Hi Hiren, i tried this, but not able to connect to the remote server using ssh  or sftp, it is not asking for the password. So is there any other way.